# Oracle 11gR2 RAC unable to connect to SCAN address

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm having a problem with my RAC environment. I am using RedHat 6, Oracle 11.2.0.4 SE. Have a 2 node RAC setup using ASM.

When connecting using SQL Developer, i can connect to my service (dev1.xxxx-dmz.local) if i connection directly to either of my cluster nodes, but when i try and use the cluster name i get the following message

```
Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
```

i have the following DNS setup 
csya-or-cluster with 3 ip addresses (172.28.1.191, 192, 193)
csya-orarac1 (172.28.1.91)
csya-orarac1-vip (172.28.1.95)
csya-orarac2 (172.28.1.92)
csya-orarac2-vip (172.28.1.96)

i have posted full details on the setup on the stackoverflow dba site

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/100957/oracle-11gr2-rac-unable-to-connect-to-scan-address

thanks

Comment: Don't crosspost and especially not if the question is offtopic here.

Comment: i was unsure of the rules of posting a link to the other site (yes i'm sure it's in the help somewhere, but life is too short to read all of that). Anyway, i wanted to post here as this site gets a lot more views than the dba site of stack overflow, and in my experience, developers and DBAs both use the main site.